# Android query using extras in the where statement

Tags: android

I having trouble with my database i was wondering how would i be able to connect two variables in a sql query.  Example i have a bus schedule that has two tables and im trying to use two put extras to query the results i want but im not sure if im able to use two extras in the where statement to replace the '?' with.  I get no errors when i do it but nothing displays but when i take away one of the extras it works but doesnt display the right information that i want.  Could someone explain why this wont work if i cant use two '?' at once or if im doing something wrong.

```
enter code here   



     idDay = getIntent().getStringExtra("Day_ID");
        idNum = getIntent().getIntExtra("BUS_ID", 0);


        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery
        (

         "SELECT A2._id, A2.dayOfWeek, A2.direction " +
         "FROM TimeTable A2 " + 
//         "WHERE A2._id = ? " +
//         "WHERE A2.dayOfWeek = ? " +
         "WHERE (A2._id = ?) AND (A2.dayOfWeek = ?) " +
         "GROUP BY A2.direction", 

//       new String[]{""+idNum});        


        new String[]{""+idNum+idDay});     
//         new String[]{""+idNum});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use 2 selection args in your query then you need 2 values in the array:

```
  new String[] { Integer.toString(idNum), Integer.toString(idDay) }
```

It doesn't matter where you get the values from.

Comment: dtmilano you have no idea how many times i went over that and i missed it every single time.  Thank you so much i am in your debt.